# how can I hide files in Nautilus permanently?

Tags: unity, nautilus, 13.04

how can I hide files in Nautilus permanently? When I uncheck the "show hidden files" button, the files get hidden. But when I open Nautilus the next time they are always back, which is quite annoying and makes Nautilus unusable.

Answer (score 3):

This key is outdated an will be ignored. Use key »**show-hidden**« in category »**org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser**« instead!

Answer (score 2):

Install dconf-tools (if not allready present). Than fire up dconf-editor
Click within dconf-editor:

Org -> gnome -> nautilus -> preferences

and clear the item "show-hidden-files"