# How to hide dotted files when they reappear after closing file manager?

Tags: 16.04

I have hidden my folders. They hide when I rename it starting with a  dot and enter ctrl+h. But when I close file manager and reopen it my hidden folders are shown automatically. So I want an answer so that I can keep my dotted folders hidden as most of them are confidencial. I have tried Nautilus but it did not work.

Comment: Possibly related: [how can I hide files in Nautilus permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287193/how-can-i-hide-files-in-nautilus-permanently)

Comment: What you're trying to do is to use "Security through obscurity" and that rarely helps as 90% of users on this site would be able to bypass your security.  [This answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/105002/344926) is a much more thorough security solution and will deter 100% of all users on this site.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to protect confidential files. Anyone with some basic knowledge of linux can find and read hidden files.

I suggest that you create an encrypted directory or encrypted partition, and store your confidential data there. You can do it manually.

Maybe the best alternative is to install a new version of Ubuntu and use 'LVM with encryption' alias 'encrypted disk', which is an automatic alternative at the installer's partitioning page.

The following link can help you with such an installation,

[Install (entire disk with lvm and encryption) in Ubuntu Desktop amd64 in Xenial 16.04.4](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/386/builds/167250/testcases/1451/results)